# If-statemenet condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a trouble understanding what does this code do :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (x++ && y++)
        y += 2;
    cout << x + y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 1 by C++. But I think it should be 2?

Why? Because in the () of if statement, I think there should only check if it's true/false, so it doesn't increment/decrement any of the integers. And since that's true by default, it increases y for 2? And output should be 0+2 = 2, but it outputs only 1?

Comment: Instead of convincing yourself that your own beliefs are the single source of truth, you could simply open a C++ text book and find out what the operators and statments **actually** do.

Comment: your assumption is way off.

Comment: x++ increments after the if statement.  When the if is checked `x` is 0, therefore false.  Once the if statement continues, x is incremented.  y+=2 is NOT processed.  This leaves `cout << 1 + 0 << endl`

Comment: Then please help me understand. I have already looked up several places and I couldn't find any information about this. I just found that the expression inside the brackets of if statement contains a boolen (true/false).

Comment: "so it doesn't increment/decrement any of the integers" ofcourse it does, just not before evaluating the statement. Here is a run down:  make x and y 0; if (0 && 0) do y+=2, after the statement do x++; x is now 1 and y is now 0; print 1+0 on the screen;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (x++ && y++)` will not do `y++` because the condition to the left of the logical and operator (`&&`) is `false` since `x++` will return `0` and increment `x` by 1.

Since `false && expression` will yield false for any expression, there is no need to evaluate the rest of it.

Hence, you end up with `x = 1` and `y = 0`.

This is called [Short-circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: Nice explanation! Liban en force.

Answer (score 1):

The post `++` operator has high priority and `&&` operator is allowed to short circuit evaluation.
What happens in `if (x++ && y++)` is that first it evaluates `x++`. The result is 0 and increments x. Since 0 is false && will short circuit the evaluation of `y++` (will not be executed). Also the if will evaluate to false and will not execute the `y+=2`.

So now you have `x=1` and `y=0`.

So the result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

it will first execute `x++` and the compiler knows that because of that the expression `x++ && y++` will be false and will ignore `y++`

as a result after that x = 1 and y = 0;

it is the same as writing `if(false && do_something())` , in this case `do_something()` will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to take a look at the operator precedence chart : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

```
//in a statement, x++ will evaluate x then increment it by 1.
//in a statement, ++x will increment x by 1 then evaluate it.
```

If you have hard time to understand it then try the below code to better understand :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (++x && ++y) // in your case, with the previous code, it gives (0 && 0)
    // instead of if statement you can try the following : cout << x++;  then cout << ++x; 
    // and notice the difference
        y += 2;
    cout << x + y << endl;
    return 0;
}
```